# how to estimate correlation between two categorical variables in a cross table form

Tags: r, correlation, cross-validation

I have two variables `AAA` and `BBB`

`AAA` has categories: 1-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50.

`BBB` has catrgories: 100-120,121-140,141-160,161-180.

Data:

```
          100-120 121-140 141-160 161-180
1-10       50      80        67      99  
11-20      60      99        77      111
21-30      88      111       121     144
31-40      99      142       188     200 
41-50      111     155       199     222
```

How do I estimate correlation between `AAA` and `BBB`. Thanks!!

Comment: `CrossTable` in the package `gmodels` provides some useful association statistics for categorical variables.

Comment: Those don't appear to be typical categorical variables. They look like binned continuous variables, which are at the very least ordinal, not categorical.

Answer (score 5):

Try standard chi-square test:

```
> chisq.test(ddf)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  ddf 
X-squared = 15.5659, df = 12, p-value = 0.2119
```

Please make sure this test is statistically sound for your data.

Data:

```
> ddf
      X100.120 X121.140 X141.160 X161.180
1-10        50       80       67       99
11-20       60       99       77      111
21-30       88      111      121      144
31-40       99      142      188      200
41-50      111      155      199      222
```

Comment: i have performed chi square, is there a way to calculate the correlation between AAA and BBB? Thanks!

Comment: Correlation is between 2 lists of numbers. You should be able to say "if x is 5, y is 10, etc". How can you convert this matrix into 2 lists of numbers? This is a table for which tests like chi-square are more appropriate.